# Why the game that I built with Phaser 3 ( and running on a VPS server ) loads slow in most of devices?

Tags: javascript, game-engine, phaser-framework

I made a card game with phaser 3, everything was good till I was working on it on local server. After running the game server on a vps server it loads very slow on most of devices. Can anyone tell me the reason of this? or what can impact the loading of the game?

Comment: There's, probably, something wrong with your code, but it's not for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to check the size of your assets (images, audio...)

Locally your browser load big images almost instantly, while from a server it need to download it first.

Comment: I did this but nothing change!

Comment: Maybe your vps has very limited bandwidth?

Answer (score -1):

I've found the solution. the best way for this is to make the game without any nodejs server providers like Webpack or Parcel!
Just finish your job with codes and then run the whole project with Apache or other webservers!